# Hiding vuforia marker

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, marker, vuforia

I'm making a Unity Vuforia Application and really want to hide marker in real time like this video. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5bjhxO4JZQ)

I also already checked an Occlusion Management sample referenced by this link(https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity/hide-real-image-target) but I couldn't understand it.

How can I hide or remove the image marker?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: lol you can't .... the marker is a real image in the real world and tracked by the real camera ... you can't simply hide it ^^ What the app did you posted the Youtube link to is rather having a virtual 3D model of a cylinder with a close to skin color/texture (maybe even by tracking the actual skin left and right next to it and copy/mirror it onto the 3D model) so you don't note it that much .... => they simply render something on top of it ... but it is still there ;)

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate your answer. By the way, have you ever used this sample? https://github.com/maximrouf/RegionCapture @derHugo